# MDC is not transfered from Hystrix thread to tomcat thread

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, hystrix, mdc

I have a classA which is running on **Tomcat thread**. ClassA is maintaining a set of MDC key-values pairs.

As the ClassA is executed, `MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()` returns (A="a", B="b", C="c")

Now, ClassA calls classB which is running on **Hystrix thread**.

When we enter ClassB, MDC from ClassA is copied and `MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()` returns (A="a", B="b", C="c").

ClassB sets a value of a variable X into MDC. 
`MDC.put("X", String.valueOf("someVal"))`
When still inside ClassB, `MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()` returns (A="a", B="b", C="c", X="someVal").

ClassA receives the MDC and tries to access the variable X.

`MDC.get(X)`

But it gets it as null because`MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()` returns (A="a", B="b", C="c").

Any suggestions why MDC is not transferred from Hystrix thread to tomcat thread?

Comment: Wild guess: Different classloader

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf("someVal")

I think , you have to use variable instead of  "someValue"
String.valueOf(variable)

Comment: I am actually using get method without quotation marks. Fixed the post

Answer (score 0):

`MDC` works in a way similar to how `ThreadLocal` works. It is linked to the current thread and does not get automatically transferred in case of threadPools (Hystrix also uses threadPool).

So you need to copy `MDC` from your main thread to hystrix thread (not your use case though) and from hystrix thread to main thread.

You can use HystrixHook to accomplish this.

Have a look at this [blog](https://medium.com/@saurav24081996/java-hystrix-and-threadlocals-95ea9e194e83)

Comment: Added details on ```MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()``` flow from ClassA>ClassB>ClassA.